# Cannot get cookie in vue-router to work. Undefined "this"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cookies, vuejs2

The problem is that I cannot get cookie in vue-router. When I try to do this: `this.$cookie.get('token');` I get `this undefined`. Even though I can use `this.$cookie` in vue components. This is my code snippet:

Vue-Router:

This is a function to check if I get token from cookie (but it doesnt work):

```
function isLoggedIn (to, from, next) {
  console.log(this.$cookie.get('token'));
}
```

And this is the route and I use that `isLoggedIn` in it:

```
{
  path: '/',
  name: 'login',
  component: Login,
  beforeEnter: isLoggedIn()
},
```

Maybe someone knows how to get that cookie ? It it setted up in vue component correctly just don't know how to pass it to vue router.

**EDIT**
So by using `Vue.cookie.get('token');` I get that `next is not a function`. This is the current function:

```
function isLoggedIn (to, from, next) {
  if(Vue.cookie.get('token')) {
    next({name: 'game'});
  } else {
    next();
  }
}
```

Okay so when I added this function directly into route like this it worked:

```
{
  path: '/',
  name: 'login',
  component: Login,
  beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
    if(Vue.cookie.get('token')) {
      next('/game');
    } else {
      next;
    }
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the **vue-cookie** plugin from npm then you will need to use this syntax outside of components:

```
function isLoggedIn (to, from, next) {
  console.log(Vue.cookie.get('token'));
}
```

With regards to your **next is not a function** error, this is because you are invoking your function with no arguments, `isLoggedIn()`, rather than passing the function reference, `isLoggedIn`, which will be invoked by the router with the appropriate arguments.

Try this instead:

```
{
  path: '/',
  name: 'login',
  component: Login,
  beforeEnter: isLoggedIn // No parentheses here
},
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Can you look at updated question and maybe can help with `next` ?

Comment: I get that cookie now btw

Comment: tack så mycket!

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the typings, you'll see that both `to` and `from` are `Route`'s. Here's their interface declaration:

```
export interface Route {
  path: string;
  name?: string;
  hash: string;
  query: Dictionary<string | (string | null)[]>;
  params: Dictionary<string>;
  fullPath: string;
  matched: RouteRecord[];
  redirectedFrom?: string;
  meta?: any;
}
```

If look at the Definition of BeforeEnter:

```
beforeEnter?: NavigationGuard;
```

If you look at the Definition of NavigationGuard:

```
export type NavigationGuard<V extends Vue = Vue> = (
  to: Route,
  from: Route,
  next: (to?: RawLocation | false | ((vm: V) => any) | void) => void
) => any
```

So as we can see, the `beforeEnter` returns a `closure` that exposes 3 methods to us: `(to, from, next)`.

As we can see the typings of both `to` and `from` are just `Route Interfaces` and `next` is a function that we pass arguments into, we can safely determine that the scope of `this` is indeed, `undefined`.

So you can either define it in the meta of the `Route` declaration and access it with `this.$meta.cookies`, or you can import the `cookie` package directly and use it with `cookies.get('token')` or you can augment the return type of the beforeEnter method:

```
beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => isLoggedIn(to, from, next, $cookies)
```

You still, cannot, use the `in component guards` as they do not expose `this` to you because they execute *before the component has been created*

Comment: Okay. I managed to get the cookie right now with `Vue.cookie.get('token')` but now it says that `next` is not a function. I have updated my question! Ty for such explanation!

Comment: Vue.cookie.get('token') Cannot read property 'get' of undefined.
Just ```$cookies.get('token')``` seems to be around though.